# How to compile C/C++ native code in Android Studio 4

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, cmake

I was trying to add C/C++ native code found in a project found in github ([here is the link](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-android)).

1. I first moved jni folder into src/main folder
2. I added below lines in my Gradle under android

   ```
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
   ```
3. When I tried to sync with Gradle I get below errors:

> make: No rule to make target
> C:/Users/PATH_TO_PROJECT/app/libjitsi/src/main/jni/opus/celt/bands.c
>
> , needed by
> 'C:/Users/PATH_TO_PROJECT/app/libjitsi/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86/objs-debug/jnopus/celt/bands.o'.
>
> Stop.
> executing external native build for ndkBuild C:\Users\PATH_TO_PROJECT\app\libjitsi\src\main\jni\Android.mk
> CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 8s

**Can anyone help me conpile those files with clear steps on How He proceeded ?**

Comment: 1. Installed NDK and configure in Android Studio 2. Use ndk-build command to compile your c/c++ code 3. Run and install the app and check it works. OR you can use cmake in Android studio which is more famous now days

Comment: **M D** Can you please provide clear steps taking into account the project I provided in the question?

Comment: Don't use this libs it's maintained.

Comment: Yeah I know, But it's for a specific purpose.

Comment: You can't use CMake here. Check the steps how to use Android.mk file to compile c/c++ code via ndk-build command. I have proper steps but it's in my laptop and I am away from my laptop. So sorry

Comment: Thanks for this direction.

Comment: I made some search as you recommended and I was able to compile. But there are still some errors. I first post an answer to let you see Where I am.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217102/discussion-between-jean-gilbert-mbula-and-m-d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that The project missed a library named **Opus audio codec** ([here is their github repository](https://github.com/xiph/opus)).

1. I downloaded the source code of opus
2. I unzipped it. And placed all its files and folder under **opus** folder located at src/main/jni
3. I deleted the win32 folder and test folder
   And it successfully  built the project